# How to calculate logits matrix in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I have LSTM model that gets one 88-dimensional vector per step at input. Each element in vector can be of class {0, 1, 2}. Output is coded as one-hot, so that means at each step I have matrix of size 3x88 at output. I would like to calculate cross-entropy loss. This is my model:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, None, INPUT_SIZE))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, None, None, OUTPUT_SIZE))
def LSTM(x_):
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(RNN_HIDDEN, state_is_tuple=True)
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=0.5)
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell] * num_layers, state_is_tuple=True)
    batch_size = tf.shape(x_)[0]
    initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

    rnn_outputs, rnn_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell,
                                                x_,
                                                initial_state=initial_state,
                                                time_major=False)

    final_projection = lambda lx: layers.linear(lx, num_outputs=OUTPUT_SIZE,
                                                activation_fn=None)
    predicted_outputs = tf.map_fn(final_projection, rnn_outputs)

    return predicted_outputs
```

Sample inputs and outputs to my network are [here](https://pastebin.com/2PedmTV3). In this sample, for inputs, size of batch is 1, there are 3 time steps, and data dimension is 88. Outputs are same, just data are transformed into one-hot vectors. So, batch size is 1 (1st dimension), there are 3 time steps (2nd dimension), there are 3 classes (3rd dimension) and data dimension is 88.

I do not know what to do with `rnn_outputs` and what to do to make `predicted_outputs` of appropriate shape so that I can call `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=batch_y_oh)`.

Code as it is now, gives me following error:
`InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[3,88] labels_size=[9,88]`

Is it even possible to calculate cross entropy like this, by feeding it directly to TF's function, or do I have to write my own function, because basically, loss would be sum of 88 cross entropies (I am thinking of iterating over columns and calling `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` for every column?

Comment: why you have 3*88 output vector？you should have 3*timsteps output vector for each input sequence，isn't it?

Comment: Because first column in output vector would correspond to one-hot encoded first element in input. So if first element in input is 0, first column in output matrix will be {1, 0, 0}, if second element in input is 1, second column in output will be {0, 1, 0}. This is related to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042272/how-to-implement-lstm-network-with-vector-input-in-each-time-step) which I solved but with MSE. Now I want to do it with cross entropy and one hot encoding since I am using discrete classes ({0, 1, 2}).

Comment: sorry, maybe you should edit your question description. Is there some matrix representing the index before embedding layer? The `cross_entropy` function is easy to implement, but I cant figure out what is your question:(

Comment: Ok, so I edited my question, and included inputs and outputs at pastebin. I really hope that now it is more clear what am I trying to do, and what am I asking.

Comment: When you have `3*88` input vector, after RNN layer, you should have `3*3` output vector, the first is timestep and second is dimentions. So you input domension should be same as output dimension